# Why the ip can't be banned with postfix blacklist?

Tags: postfix, blacklist

```
vim /etc/postfix/main.cf
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access
```

Add some ips in /etc/postfix/access

```
vim  /etc/postfix/access
86.111.171.141  REJECT 
191.96.249.63   REJECT
```

Restart postfix.

```
postmap hash:/etc/postfix/access
systemctl restart  postfix
```

After serveral times.

```
tail  /var/log/maillog
Oct 30 10:18:45 localhost postfix/smtpd[3491]: connect from unknown[86.111.171.141]
Oct 30 10:18:45 localhost postfix/smtpd[3491]: warning: unknown[86.111.171.141]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Oct 30 10:18:46 localhost postfix/smtpd[3491]: disconnect from unknown[86.111.171.141]      
Oct 30 10:18:45 localhost postfix/smtpd[3491]: connect from unknown[191.96.249.63]
Oct 30 10:18:45 localhost postfix/smtpd[3491]: warning: unknown[191.96.249.63]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Oct 30 10:18:46 localhost postfix/smtpd[3491]: disconnect from unknown[191.96.249.63]
```

Why the ip can't be banned with postfix blacklist?

Answer (score 6):

Because the `check_sender_access` is a [`smtpd_sender_restriction`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restriction) and, therefore, performed

> for the `MAIL FROM` address, domain, parent domains, or `localpart@`, and execute the corresponding action.

If you wan't to block IP addresses using Postfix, take a look at [`smtpd_helo_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_helo_restrictions), instead. There's a possibility to `check_helo_a_access` for the IP addresses for the `HELO` / `EHLO` hostname. Remember add `smtpd_helo_required = yes` and possibly `reject_unknown_helo_hostname`, too.